# Can we create pipelines to run DAX queries on Azure Analysis Service Tabular Models from ADF or Synapse Analytics?

Tags: powerbi, dax, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-analysis-services

How can we create ADF pipeline to run DAX query from ADF(or Synapse Analytics) to AAS Tabular Models and get the data stored into tables in Azure Data Warehouse Tables or in a .csv file?

I've read about creating a .Net library for connecting to Analysis Services servers and querying data from .NET code. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Hey, do you by any chance have a sql server in your architecture? If yes, then you can leverage out of box feature to execute the query

Comment: There is no direct method to do it from ADF, you would have to do it via an azure function, so call that from your pipeline.

Comment: Hey @jon, you can create a linked server to aas and execute the query on the aas via the database via adf.

Comment: @Nandan I do have a sql server in the architecture. So are you suggesting I move the data to server and then query it? Also in above comment you said we can "execute the query on the aas via the database via adf". Will that be a SQL query or DAX?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked server mapping to aas on the sql server.
Create a linked service in adf to the sql database and query the aas via the sql database.

my blog for reference :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/16/copy-data-from-ssas-aas-through-azure-data-factory

Comment: Will this work with Azure SQL Server?

Comment: Nope. On prem Or iaas sql or sql mi wherein you can create a linked server

Comment: Don't have provisions for spinning up any of those. Any other solution?

Comment: This and explicit. Net code are the ways that i know. I am not sure there is any other direct way without explicit coding. Unlike powerbi which has a rest api to execute queries, aaa doesn't have any that I know of